# Is it possible to get the line number of a quoted string literal?

Tags: elixir

I'm writing a linter for Elixir that largely works by inspecting the AST returned from `Code.string_to_quoted/2`. When my application finds something deemed a style violation I report it with the line number found in the node's metadata.

Strings are one of the literals that are the same in their quoted form, and thus have no metadata. How can I get line number when I'm only looking at the string, and can't draw the line number from the surrounding expression.

For example, I want this string

```
~s(\n"\\"")
```

to result in a reported error on line number 2 when inspected, but the return value is without line numbers.

```
iex(18)> Code.string_to_quoted ~S(\n"\\""), lines: true
{:ok, "\""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not possible to directly get the line number from a quoted expression, it is possible to get the line numbers for string literals from tokenized source code.

The Elixir compiler's tokenizer is actually part of the standard library, and be access with the `:elixir_tokenizer` module like so:

```
source_string
|> String.to_char_list
|> :elixir_tokenizer.tokenize( 1, [] )
```

If you have this code:

```
IO.puts "Hello, world!"
```

You'll get something like this back:

```
{:ok, 2,
[{:aliases, 1, [:IO]}, {:., 1}, {:identifier, 1, :puts},
  {:bin_string, 1, ["Hello, world!"]}, {:eol, 1}]}
```

The second item in the `:bin_string` tuple is the line number.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get line numbers for literals because they are represented as themselves. It will work for everything else though:

```
iex(1)> Code.string_to_quoted "a"
{:ok, {:a, [line: 1], nil}}
```

Comment: Aye, this is the problem. I presume this means there is no other obvious way to get the line number for strings like this then- that's a shame.